# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder Configuration update at runtime

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring cloud stream along with Kafka binders to connect to a Kafka cluster using SASL. The SASL config looks as follows:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.sasl.jaas.config= .... required username="..." password="..."
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
```

**I want to update the username and password programmatically/at runtime, how can I do that in Spring Cloud Stream using Spring Kafka binders?**

*Side note:
Using `BinderFactory` I can get reference to `KafkaMessageChannelBinder` which has `KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties`, in its `configuration` hashmap I can see those configurations but I want to know how can I update the configuration at runtime such that those changes are reflected in the connections as well?*

```
@Autowired
BinderFactory binderFactory

....

public void foo()
{
    KafkaMessageChannelBinder k = (KafkaMessageChannelBinder)binderFactory.getBinder(null, MessageChannel.class);
    // Using debugger I inspected k.configurationProperties.configuration which has the SASL properties I need to update
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jaas username and password can be provided using configuration, which also means that they can be overridden using the same properties at runtime.

Here is an example: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/multi-binder-samples/kafka-multi-binder-jaas/src/main/resources/application.yml#L26

At runtime, you can override the values set in `application.properties`. For example, if you are running the app using `java -jar`, you could simply pass the property along with it: `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.jaas.options.username`. Then this new value will take effect for the duration of the application run.

Comment: How do I override these properties? Do I simply override the application.properties file? Or do I change some configuration objects?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to override the properties.

Comment: I don't want to restart the application, I want to update it at runtime, meaning that lets say if I get the credentials using an API call then I want to simply update my Kafka connection using those new credentials

Comment: That may not work (at least with the current way Kafka works). Check with the wider Kafka community to see if that is possible to do so for a Kafka client app in general. If it's possible, then we can make it happen from Spring Cloud Stream as well.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem yesterday and spent about 3-4 hours in order to figure out how to programmatically update the username and password in Spring Cloud Stream using Spring Kafka binders as one cannot/should not store passwords inside Git.(Spring Boot Version 2.5.2)
Overriding the bean KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties works.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties(KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties properties) {
    String saslJaasConfigString = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=${USERNAME_FROM_EXTERNAL_SYSTEM_LIKE_VAULT} password=${PASSWORD_FROM_EXTERNAL_SYSTEM_LIKE_VAULT}"
    Map<String, String> configMap = properties.getConfiguration();
    configMap.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, saslJaasConfigString);
    return properties;
}
```